# Как сделать адаптивное навигационное меню?

Tags: html, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка, меню

Изучаю адаптивную верстку на bootstrap 4 и появилась проблема с навигационным меню, не могу понять как его грамотно адаптировать, особенно на маленькие экраны. Использую только сетку bootstrap.

```
<nav class="title_page__navigation col-4">
                <ul class="title_page__navigation">
                    <li class="title_page__item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="title_page__item"><a href="#">What we do ?</a></li>
                    <li class="title_page__item"><a href="#">Testimonial</a></li>
                    <li class="title_page__item"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
            </nav>
```

На данный момент сделал навигационное меню, логотип и форму но вот как все это грамотно адаптировать не могу понять[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для адаптивного меню можно использовать встроенный в bootstrap класс navbar — https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: но придется использовать все стили и что-то писать под себя. Разве это лучший вариант ?

Comment: Смотря в какой степени вы хотите использовать bootstrap. Если вы хотите отказаться от встроенных классов, относящихся к меню, вам придётся придумать или взять готовый дизайн адаптивного меню и в стилях привязаться к необходимому разрешению экрана с помощью media-queries, меняя в них стили вашего меню.

Comment: Хм..
интересно
а как тогда использовать какие-то конкретные классы ? по отдельности их подключать или как ?

Comment: Какие-то конкретные - уточните, пожалуйста, что имеется в виду. Если вы хотите использовать встроенные классы бутстрапа, то нужно добавить их в разметку, заодно изменив ее до состояния примера по ссылке выше. Если стиль бутстрапа не устраивает (размеры, отступы, цвета и тд), то нужно будет модифицировать уже свои классы

Comment: hedgehogues, обновил ответ, но код примера использует внешние зависимости в виде подключаемых через cdn js/css, которые также могут стать недействительными. Мне кажется, в данном случае корректнее давать ссылку на документацию фреймворка, т. к. ответ не касается какой-то конкретной проблемы, а является общим.